# Select from two tables compare on id remove if certain column has data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. I'll stick the outlet in for reference.

*Outlet*

```
ID  Outlet_Name
-----------------
1   Big Bar
2   Bigger Bar
```

*Master_Stock*

```
ID  Stock_Name
--------------------
1   Heineken
2   Speights ALe
3   Lion Red
4   Chavey Blue
5   Tui Beer
```

*Outlet_Stock*

```
ID  Stock_ID  Outlet_ID
--------------------------
1   1         1
2   2         1
3   3         1
```

How can I select all that is in `Master_Stock`, compare it against `Outlet_Stock` and remove it based on the `Outlet_ID` ?

For example - the query would leave 
Master_Stock

```
ID 
4
5
```

as Outlet 1 already has 1, 2 and 3.

This is running inside a Microsoft SQL Server Management.

```
SELECT *
FROM Stock
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM outlet_stock
                  WHERE stock.id = outlet_stock.stock_id 
                    AND outlet_stock.outlet_id <> '1')
```

I expect the output to only contain the ones that are in master stock that aren't in outlet_stock for a certain outlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big part of the solution is selecting from `master_stock` rather than `stock`.  Then you need to get the subquery right:

```
SELECT ms.*
FROM master_stock ms
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM outlet_stock os
                  WHERE ms.id = os.stock_id AND
                        os.outlet_id = 1
                 );
```

Comment: Well that was super quick and worked a charm. Thanks Ive spent hours puzzled at this. Thanks a lot Gordon will accept when times up :)